# Getting Unix time or epoch in VHDL

Tags: random, vhdl

To introduce some randomness in my testbench I would like to use pseudo-random numbers seeded with the current Unix time or epoch. Is there a (non-synthesizable ofc) function in VHDL for that? I need it to work in VHDL 2008.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2019 16.5.4 Date and time API, but there is likely no simulator that can claim with a straight face to support that revision today. EPOCH returns a REAL which would give you 56 bits of accuracy converted to an INTEGER (64 bits in -2019). We're not that close to the end of the 64 bit range of a UNIX epoch to be a problem. You could always pass a generic in a tool supporting command line generics and compliant with an earlier revision of the standard. For repeatability  in producing errors the value could be stored.

Comment: Updated the question. The standard I'm targeting is 2008 so VHDL 2019 functions are unavailable to me.

Comment: To do it in VHDL-2008, your scripts are going to have to be able to pass in a generic with the UNIX / Epoch time.    This is probably the best way to do it anyway as once you get it working, if / when you find a failure you need to be able to repeat the exact same test that failed.

Generally pseudo random is good enough for test case generation, however, what you are proposing is good for running new additional tests as an extra layer (beyond your other verification tests) of testing the design when the verification space is large.

Comment: You've managed to avoid specifying the VHDL tool implementation and passing generics is implementation dependent and non-portable. Can you ask a specific programming question to make this on-topic and avoid a recommendation question?

Comment: Are you running these in a CI system? simply passing the system time would work, but may cause repeatability problems. In CI, in the past, ive simply passed in the CI job number as the seed, as this is always different for each run and makes re-creating the run locally a simply matter of looking up the job number. Otherwise you can get TCL (or any other language) to generate a random number for you as the seed.

Comment: Can you show me how this is done? I'm simply running my testbench with ghdl 1.0 like this: `ghdl --elab-run --std=08 tb` I just want some random numbers to "spice up" my testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply passing a generic parameter value on the same command line you use to run the simulation? Example with `bash`:

```vhdl
entity foo is
  generic(seed: natural := 0);
end entity foo;

architecture bar of foo is
begin
  assert false report natural'image(seed);
end architecture bar;
```

```sh
$ ghdl -a --std=08 foo.vhd
$ ghdl -r --std=08 foo
foo.vhd:7:3:@0ms:(assertion error): 0
$ ghdl -r --std=08 foo -gseed=$(date +%s)
foo.vhd:7:3:@0ms:(assertion error): 1648027085
```